# VS 2015 не могу установить NuGet библитеку

Tags: visual-studio-2015

В `VS 2015` через `NuGet` устанавливаю `BlockchainAPI`. Установку отклоняет и выдает ошибку

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Could not install package 'BlockchainAPI 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Похоже она сделана под dotnetcore 1.1

Comment: @vitidev и как мне в проект поменять на dotnetcore 1.1? 
в папке `dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App` есть версия `1.1.0`

Comment: @Nikita пересоздайте проект. У проекта .NET Core другая структура

Comment: @PavelMayorov При создании проекта, можно выбрать только Framework, где выбрать .Net Core?

Comment: Templates - Visual C# - .NET Core. Если подобного нет - значит, надо до-установить студию.